# Multiple Session(Admin & User) Handling in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I Had create Admin Panel as Back End & User Panel as Front end.I want to maintain session of admin as well as User.Will you have any solution?

Comment: Differentiate the user session like this $_SESSION['admin']['username'];   $_SESSION['user']['username'];

Answer (score 0):

simple Differentiate the session like this

**Admin**

```
$_SESSION['admin']['username']='admin_username'; 
         ^^^^^^^^^
```

**User**

```
$_SESSION['user']['username']='user_username'; 
         ^^^^^^^^
```

**IN codeigniter**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('admin',$array_of_admin_data);
$this->session->set_userdata('user',$array_of_user_data);
```

then retrieve each seesion data using

```
$this->session->userdata('admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create separate Controller for Admin and User.
2. While Login set session of admin and User in separate names.for admin `$this->session->set_userdata('admin','admin_id')`for user`$this->session->set_userdata('user','user_id')`
3. Write `__construct()` function at top of each controller and check
   session there.